# Saving an array of all server members using Discord.py-Rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is there a way I can return an array of all the members of a server? I'm trying to make a "Who would" command where someone does "!whowould do something" And then it randomly picks a user from the server and says "USER would do something" I tried this.

```
@bot.command()
async def whowould(ctx, *args):
    print(ctx.guild.members)
```

I tried that to just see what it did, but it gathered more information than just the usernames and tags of the user.

I want to be able to save the members of a server as an array so i can use the random module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members) is already a list of `Member` objects. You should use `random.choice` to select one, then use [`Member.display_name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.display_name) or [`Member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mention) to get thir name or mention them:

```
@bot.command()
asyc def ping_random(ctx):
    member = random.choice(ctx.guild.members)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}")
```